# Aggregate the grouped values on many specific columns from list

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, aggregate

I'd like to perfom `groupBy()` operation with specific `agg()`.

```py
df = df.groupBy("x", "y").agg(F.max("a").alias("a"), F.max("b").alias("b"))
```

But is there any way to aggregation using list of columns? I don't want to hardcode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```
list_of_cols = ["a", "b"]
df = df.groupBy("x", "y").agg(*[F.max(x).alias(x) for x in list_of_cols])
```